# Download/ Deserialize JSON File

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I try to download and deserialise an JSON file.

I have this piece of code but when I run my apps i don't download my file

```
public static async void btnGet_Tap()
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        try
        {
            Uri source = new Uri("http://88.174.101.185:15343/share/CkEtT9llw2BCbmPL/all-cards.json");
            StorageFile destinationFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                "all-cards.json", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

            BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-- Download OK");

            // Getting JSON from file if it exists, or file not found exception if it does not  

            StorageFile storageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("all-cards.json");
            string configData = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);


            // deserialize back to our product!  
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" -- Read OK : " + configData);
            RootObject card = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(configData);
            // and show it   
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Deserialization OK" + card.meta.patch);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

My error :

```
-- Download OK
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
 -- Read OK : 
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App3.exe
   at App3.Control.<btnGet_Tap>d__0.MoveNext()
The program '[2364] App3.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Yes but this topic don't really help me ... I know my File is empty and my String Object is null but i don't whats is wrong in my code

Comment: If you're attempting to deserialize something from a `null` string, I'd either expect an exception or `null` to be returned. It looks like the latter is occurring. Check where the error is occurring, and make sure the object you're referencing on that line isn't null.

Comment: I'm agree but the problem isnt the null Exeption , I don't know why i don't download my File.

Comment: I see you edited your question, alright, that makes a little more sense then. Have you tried downloading something that you *know* works, like, say, `http://google.com`? Then at least we can rule out anything that might be the fault of your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server gives a 404 response, so you actually don't get the right data.